# X value of each element in list

Tags: r

how do I get the x value of each element in the list.

example:

```
list1 <- list(1:3,4:6)
list1
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 4 5 6
```

Imaginary function I'm looking for:

```
function(list1, 1)
# [1] 1 4
function(list2, 2)
# [1] 2 5
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sapply` or `lapply`, in combination with the `[` extraction function (see `?Extract` for more info) like so:

```
> sapply(list1,"[",1)
[1] 1 4
```

...or with a list output:

```
> lapply(list1,"[",1)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 4
```